# How to create an Oauth client for website https://onehub.com/ using REST services

Tags: c#, java, asp.net-mvc-3, oauth, oauth-2.0

My requirement is like that, I want to create an OAuth client for the website 
https://onehub.com/. I got all the required information from that site but I don't know from where I need to start.

1. Application URI `http://XYZ/SIDemo`
2. Redirect URI `http://XYZTest/SIDemo`
3. Client ID -->`9rtk1k9fsdgziiuvakujytuea6doxpk`
4. Client Secret--> `Only available immediately after the Client is created.`

I am not getting what is Application URI and Redirect URI ,This website is basically used for Uploading and downloading files. I want Oauth for this site So that I can able to share files with my clients like for different clients different folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably do some homework on OAuth.

The `application URI` is where your web app resides. I'm not sure of Onehub's API, but this is generally what happens in the OAuth flow - 
i) You register your app and get client credentials (you already have those!). I'll talk of `redirect_uri` later.
ii) User clicks on a log in with onehub button that you have added to your website (which resides at the application URI).
iii) basically, you have delegated the login process to one-hub. Onehub's login page would open, it would prompt the user to accept/decline the permissions that your app has demanded.
iv) Now, once the user accepts -> Onehub would send an access token/authorization code (depending on the flow) to the `redirect_uri` link that you provide. 
So basically, you need to catch the access token in that page, hit Onehub's REST API (for which you are using OAuth) with the token and perhaps redirect to your own page once onehub returns the info to you.

Comment: Thanks for ur help i want to know how i will use application uri and redoirect uri my code is like that application uri--https://ws.onehub.com,this is login page and how to give redirect uri

Comment: I'm assuming that you are using Onehub's OAuth and will hit Onehub APIs to upload/download files.
You write a web app - at yourdomain.com -> that's your application uri. That's what the user sees, once he logs in with onehub -> one hub will send an access token to -> yourdomain.com/red.php (say) where you will catch the token and redirect to a (say) user portal. Where according to user choices you hit a Onehub API with the token.

Comment: I'm just speaking of the general OAuth workflow, you got to figure out the exact flow and API endpoints for Onehub yourself.

Comment: i am not getting any code from there as i am a beginner m facing a lot of problem. application uri means i have to design on login screen in .net .how user will logs in to onhub i am not providing credential

Comment: I'm not sure how Onehub API works, I bet they would have provided enough Documentation. As a general rule, just remember that the login module is like a black box, the OAuth provider would handle it for you, and return the access token!! You don't have to worry about the log-in feature.

Comment: hei i ve one more doubt.Now i am getting access token but its showing that 401 unauthorised error.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you much with it. I know stuff about OAuth but I haven't read Onehub's API documentation. You'll have to do that yourself. See this link - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v2r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.tivoli.fim.doc_6.2.2%2Fconfig%2Fconcept%2FOAuth20Workflow.html . It'll help you understand the workflows, maybe you could relate one of them to Onehub and act accordingly.